# Install Pycurl after mac update to High Sierra - SSL error

Tags: pycurl, macos-high-sierra

I updated my mac to high sierra, and now I can't install pycurl. It fails with this message : `Curl is configured to use SSL, but we have not been able to determine which SSL backend it is using. Please see PycURL documentation for how to specify the SSL backend manually.`

I searched on the documentation and the web and I found some solution that not fix my problem. the most popular is this one :

```
pip uninstall pycurl
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
pip install pycurl
```

here is the complete error

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A solution similar to the one you found worked for me when issued from within my virtualenv. I use Homebrew as a package manager on macOS High Sierra, and Pipenv to manage my project dependencies and virtualenv. The error emerged after adding the PyVimeo API Library, which has PycURL as a dependency, to my project.

The generated errors were, first,

> src/pycurl.c:137:4: warning: #warning "libcurl was compiled with SSL
>   support, but configure could not determine which library was used;
>   thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may cause
>   random crashes on SSL requests" [-Wcpp]

then,

> ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is
>   different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)

[As mentioned in the PycURL docs](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#ssl), the solution was to "tell [PycURL's] setup.py what SSL backend is used." Setting the environment variables recommended in the output of `brew info openssl`, alone, did not solve the problem.

Then I found a [tangentially related Github issue comment](https://github.com/siznax/wptools/issues/68#issuecomment-323205783) and tried the following from within my project's virtualenv:

```
(env)$ pip uninstall pycurl
(env)$ pip install --upgrade pip
(env)$ export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
(env)$ export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
(env)$ export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
(env)$ pip install pycurl
```

The `install` command gave this output:

> Collecting pycurl   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: pycurl   Running setup.py
>   bdist_wheel for pycurl ... done   Stored in directory:
>   /Users/me/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/d2/85/ae/ebf5ff0f1378a69d082b4863df492bf54c661bf6306a2bd
>   Successfully built pycurl
>   tuspy 0.2.1 has requirement pycurl==7.43.0,
>   but you'll have pycurl 7.43.0.2 which is incompatible. Installing
>   collected packages: pycurl Successfully installed pycurl-7.43.0.2

I noted the (somewhat petty?) `tuspy` error and trudged on. This time, my script ran without PycURL complaining.